# Сложить значения полей таблицы yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть таблица Clients и связанна с ней таблицая Orders. В Orders есть поле sum, которое содержит информацию о сумме заказа.
Один клиент может иметь несколько заказов. Я извлекаю информацию о клиенте и о всех его заказах. Возможно ли как-то сложить сумму всех заказов, например в aftetFind? Или нужно обязательно делать еще один запрос к бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ 1**

Не проверял, но вероятно можно так, afterFind в Orders или Customer, неважно - это повлияет только на то, как выводить эту информацию

```
public function afterFind() {
   $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(название столбца с суммой заказа) FROM ваша таблица WHERE customer_id=".$this->customer_id);
   $sum = $command->queryScalar();
   $this->sum = $sum;
}
```

**Способ 2**

**в модель Customer**

```
public function afterFind() {
       $this->orders_sum = Orders::getOrdersSum($this->user_id);
    }
```

**в модель Orders**

```
public static function getOrdersSum(int $user_id) : int {
    $return = 0;
    foreach (self::find()->where(['user_id' => $user_id])->all() as $item) {
       $order_amount = (int)$item['amount'] // сумма 1ого заказа
       $return += $order_amount;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. без дополнительного запроса это никак нельзя сделать? А если во view через цикл посчитать сумму, будет ли это считаться нормальной практикой?

Comment: @t16bz во view лучше не делать никаких операций, кроме вывода. Вы можете в контроллере пройтись циклом по $customer->orders и через него посчитать сумму

Comment: Я думаю, лучше считать в модели `Clients`, к примеру создать метод `sumOrders`, который выведет сумму всех заказов. Опять же все зависит от того, будете ли вы выводить заказы на странице. Что будет если заказов у клиента будет очень много. В этом случаи, я думаю, лучше сделать еще запрос в БД или модифицировать текущий, чтоб еще он попутно подсчитал сумму всех заказов.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов а можете привести пример, как в модели Clients получить все значения из таблицы Orders?

Comment: @t16bz дополнил свой ответ, смотри 2ой способ

Comment: Второй способ лучше модернизировать с перебором `$this->orders as $item`. `$this->orders` это метод `getOrders(){return $this->hasMany(...);}`

Comment: `
public function sumOrders() = {
    $this->getOrders()->where(['client_id' => $this->id])->sum();
}

public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, ['client_id' => 'id']);
}
`
Я бы не стал делать в afterFind, т. к. не понятно где именно вы будете использовать данную модель. Скорей всего такое поведение вам нужно будет на пару страниц, а использовать модель, скорей всего, придется часто.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно одним запросом, то можно так:

В классе `Client` добавить поле для суммы заказов, например `$ordersSum`:

```
class Client extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $ordersSum;
    ...
}
```

Затем где нужно выводить клиентов ищем их таким запросом:

```
$clients = Client::find()
    ->alias('c')
    ->leftJoin('{{%orders}} o', 'c.id=o.user_id')
    ->select('c.*, SUM(o.sum) as ordersSum')
    ->groupBy('c.id')
    ->all();
```

Теперь во вьюхе можно выводить и сумму заказов по каждому клиенту:

```
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    echo $client->name . ' -- ' . $client->ordersSum . '<br />';
}
```

P.S.Помните, что бывает лучше сделать два или три маленьких запроса к БД, чем один сложный двойной или тройной join-запрос.